# Getting the highest number from an ArrayList of different data types

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I am working on a program that prompts the user for a Name, An age and a Gender. The program is supposed to give me a list of Name, Age and Gender from each input AND ALSO tell me who is the oldest person from that list. I have created an ArrayList to hold the values and I am ok using an enhanced loop to print out the names, ages and genders. What I am having trouble with is getting the program to print out the highest (oldest) number from the ArrayList. I have created an alternative way to do it by creating an Additional ArrayList with only the ages but I don't seem to find a way to get this from the Original ArrayList. This alternative way gives me only the highest number from the extra array but if I wanted to print the name of the oldest person with his/her age, it won't work. I will appreciate some help to figure this out. I am really new to Java.

Here my code so far:

From Person Class:

```
package person;

public class Person {
    private String name ; 
    private int age; 
    private String gender; 
    private int oldestPerson;

    public Person(String name1, int age1, String gender1){
        name = name1; 
        age = age1;
        gender = gender1; 
    } 

    public String getName(){
        return name;  
    }

    public int getAge(){
        return age; 
    }

    public String getGender() {
        return gender; 
    }

    public void changeName(String newName){
        name = newName; 
    }

    public void changeAge(int newAge){
        age = newAge; 
    }

    public void changeGender(String newGender){
        gender = newGender; 
    }

    public int getOldest(int max){
        if (age > max){
            max = age;
        }
        return oldestPerson; 
    }
}
```

From personTester class:

```
package person;

import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class personTester {

    public static void main(String [] args){
        ArrayList<Person> personList = new ArrayList<Person>();
        ArrayList<Integer> personAges = new ArrayList<Integer>();  //extra array
        boolean Done = false; 
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        while(!Done){
            System.out.println("enter a name");
            String name = input.next();

            System.out.println("enter an age");
            int age = input.nextInt();

            System.out.println("enter a gender");
            String gender= input.next(); 

            personList.add(new Person(name, age, gender)); //put a person inside an arraylist
            personAges.add(new Integer(age));

            System.out.println("Press Y to exit or N to continue");
            String choice = input.next(); 
            if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y")){
                Done=true;
            }
        }

        for(Person e :personList){
           System.out.println("Name: "+e.getName() +" -   Age: "+ e.getAge()+" - 
     Gender: " + e.getGender());
        } // getting the highest number from the aditional array. 

        int max = 0; 
        for (int ages: personAges){
            if (ages > max){
                max = ages; 
            }
        }

        System.out.println("The oldest person in the list is " + max);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Imagine the following real-life scenario: There is a group of persons which don't know anything about each other, and you as bystander want to know who is the oldest. You can't ask a person: Are you the oldest? Because they don't know how old the other people in the group are.

Instead, you'll have to ask each person how old they are, and based on that determine yourself who is the oldest.

---

So in your code, the `private int oldestPerson;` field and `public int getOldest(int max)` method should be removed from Person. They don't know if they are the oldest, they can only give you their `age`.
And you (the programmer) should ask the age to all persons and determine based on that who is the oldest.

So change this part of your code:

```
int max = 0; 
for(int ages : personAges){
  if(ages > max){
    max = ages; 
  }
}
System.out.println("The oldest person in the list is " + max);
```

To this:

```
int maxAge = 0; 
for(Person p : personList){
  int pAge = p.getAge();
  if(pAge  > maxAge){
    maxAge = pAge; 
  }
}

System.out.println("The oldest person in the list is " + maxAge + " years old");
```

And you can also remove the `ArrayList<Integer> personAges= new ArrayList<Integer>();  //extra array` and `personAges.add(new Integer(age));`

Like this you are getting the ages from the Persons (using your getter `getAge()` and store it in `maxAge`).

Comment: Thank you so much! This really clarifies it for me!

Comment: @Monique You're welcome! :) Since you've stated you are new to Java I kept it basic, without too much new things. It is true that you can also solve this in less code with a `Comparator` or a Java 8 lambda as the other answers suggested, but that would change your code a bit too much, imho. The most important thing is to learn what was wrong with your code and why, so next time you'll be able to solve it yourself. ;)

Answer (score 0):

I created a test list of `Person`s to illustrate my solution:

```
List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
persons.add(new Person("Kees", 100, "M"));
persons.add(new Person("Kees", 0, "V"));
persons.add(new Person("Kees", 10, "V"));
persons.add(new Person("Kees", 1, "M"));
```

Then using Java 8 streams you can sort on the age of the Person (old to young by using `reversed()`)and then get the first result:

```
Person oldest = persons.stream()
  .sorted(Comparator.comparing(Person::getAge).reversed())
  .findFirst().get();
```

Added a standard `toString()` method to your Person class to print the result

```
System.out.println(oldest);
```

Which now prints:

```
Person [name=Kees, age=100, gender=M]
```

An alternative way of printing the details of the list of persons uses `forEach()` instead of a for-loop

```
persons.forEach(p -> System.out.println(p.getName() + " " + p.getAge() + " " + p.getGender()));
```

Comment: Since I am still very new to java, I haven't been able to use Comparators. But I will get myself into it. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

one approach is to use the streams `max` method and pass in your own `comparator`:

```
ArrayList <Person> personList= new ArrayList<Person>();
Person oldestPerson = personList.stream().max(Comparator.comparingInt(Person::getAge)).get();
System.out.println("oldest persons name is: " + oldestPerson.getName() + " age is: " + oldestPerson.getAge());
```

Answer (score 0):

> I have created an alternative way to do it by creating an Aditional
>   ArrayList with only the ages but I don't seem to find a way to get
>   this from the Original array list.

This is quite frankly a horrible idea and you should forget that way as quickly as possible.

You are already iteration through your whole Person List. All you now have to do is create a variable that holds the Person with the highest Age (Lets call it `highestAgePerson`). In each iteration of your for loop you now check if the Person you are currently printing has an age that is higher than that of the Person denoted by your `highestAgePerson`, and set `highestAgePerson` to that new Person if thats the case.

```
final Person highestAgePerson = null; // initialize to null
for(Person e :personList){
    System.out.println("Name: "+e.getName() +" -   Age: "+ e.getAge()+" - 
    Gender: " + e.getGender());
    if(highestAgePerson==null || highestAgePerson.getAge() < e.getAge()) {
        highestAgePerson = e;
    }
}
```

After that you will have the person with the highest Age inside the variable `highestAgePerson` and can print it and its attributes.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **Comparator** to sort your list with age and get the oldest one, for example :

```
String choice;
do {
    System.out.println("enter a name");
    String name = input.next();
    System.out.println("enter an age");
    int age = input.nextInt();
    System.out.println("enter a gender");
    String gender = input.next();
    personList.add(new Person(name, age, gender)); //put a person inside an 
    System.out.println("Press Y to exit or N to continue");
    choice = input.next();
} while (choice.equalsIgnoreCase("Y"));

Collections.sort(personList, new Comparator<Person>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(Person o1, Person o2) {
        return o1.getAge() - o2.getAge();
    }
});

System.out.println("The oldest person in the list is " + 
    personList.get(personList.size()-1).getName() + 
    " His/Her age is " + personList.get(personList.size()-1).getAge());
```